# Export Outlook message body number to Excel

Tags: excel, import, outlook

Each day I have to open approximately 30 emails and take one number from each email and place it into an Excel sheet. I have found how to use Access to import the Outlook emails and retrieve the number I need. But that means using Access imported to Excel.

Can I do something similar with just Excel?

Comment: I have in the past but I was thinking since exporting was possible with Access it should also be possible with Excel. I have also used the "Get External Data" feature within Excel for SQL queries but using it with Outlook is not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was trying to get message body from Outlook for Office 365 without success; copying the view still did not isolate message body to a single cell. Frustrating!

Then I recognized it was possible to "get data" "from microsoft exchange." Problem Solved!

Connect to Exchange (Power Query) 
Use Excel's Get & Transform (Power Query) experience to connect to a Microsoft Exchange server.

Click the Data tab, then Get Data > From Other Sources > From Microsoft Exchange. If you don't see the Get Data button, the click New Query > From Other Sources > From Microsoft Exchange

Power Query Data Sources

Next

1.In the Access an Exchange Server dialog box, specify your Email Address and Password.

2.Click Save.

3.In the Microsoft Exchange Autodiscover Service dialog box, select Allow to allow the Exchange Service to trust your credentials.